# Android Studio : SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer.h: No such file or directory

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio

Trying to run the Android Crossexample app that comes with the Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine from superpowered (https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine/tree/master/Android/CrossExample/app/src/main/java/com/superpowered/crossexample).

I'm getting: `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer.h: No such file or directory`.

Based on @Stacks13 suggestion, I'm wondering if my local.properties file needs something more.  Here's what it's got now:

`ndk.dir=/Users/mh/android-ndk-r12b
sdk.dir=/Users/mh/phonegap/android-sdk/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk`

I'm new to Android Studio and Superpowered and would appreciate suggestions as to how to resolve this.

The solution offered by Даниил Дедов worked for me.  However, it brings up two questions:

1) I notice the `local.properties` file says at the top:
   
   `## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
   # Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!`

   So it seems wrong that editing it is effective.

2) Can anyone tell me why `superpowered.dir` is gray?  (See screen shot below.)

[image]

[image: no such file or directory error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will help you.

**Add a path to SuperpoweredSDK\Superpowered directory in local.properties:**

```
superpowered.dir=C\:\\SuperpoweredSDK\\Superpowered
```

Comment: This worked, although my path to `Superpowered` is different. I still have a couple of questions, which I will add to my main post.  Thank you, @Даниил Дедов

Comment: According to your first question : "The local.properties file is generated by Android Studio, its header contains a big warning asking to not modify it because “the content can be erased”.
According to (a discussion I had with) the Android SDK team, this file is actually properly accessed by Android Studio and if you add content, it should not be lost in the future. As it is part of the development environment, we can consider local.properties safe enough to use as the content can rarely be removed."  [gradle.org](https://gradle.org/blog/gradle-the-build-system-for-android/)

Comment: Gabor Szanto, CTO of Superpowered, put it this way to me in an email: "Android Studio is buggy and often tells you wrong things. Putting the paths into local.properties is the recommended way to set up local specific paths. `superpowered.dir` is gray because of an Android Studio bug. That path is clearly used in the build.gradle for the app."

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are available here -
https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine

Just scroll down to README.md

Comment: Hmmm.  I did go over that.  Maybe my paths in `local.properties` are insufficient?  I added to my question based on that idea.

Comment: I don't think that will help @user1147171 since that page does not explicitly say where to put header files and how to set up a project. He obviously has already seen the github page.